# CSS background image on laravel 5.4 with {{ asset('path/image.png') }}

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Can I write css for background-image like this on laravel project?

```
.some-class {
  background-image: url('{{ asset('path/image.png') }}');
}
```

Comment: You can write this inline in the view.

Comment: Ok, thank for your suggestion

Answer (score 11, accepted):

background images are relative to the css file. Ordinarily you would just specify the path like

```
.some-class{
background-image: url("/img/background-header.jpg"); 
}
```

The above css code works if you are accessing images from public folder like for example

```
public/
    img/
       background-header.jpg
```

Comment: so, the slash on before img it mean access photo from root, to the path of image?

Comment: Exactly , / means the root of the current drive;

./ means the current directory;

../ means the parent of the current directory.

Comment: Console error shows GET http://localhost:8000/css/img/background-header, note the "css" folder, the correct solution is move up one level like this: url("../img/background-header.jpg");